# Live video streaming

Tags: php, actionscript-3

Can anyone help me to give me a path or instruction how can i stream video live by the help of PHP like live tv? I am willing not to use flash media server. If it is must to use it then which server is free and reliable?

Answer (score 2):

Use ustream, justin.tv or a similar server to save yourself a ton of time/headaches/resources. These people have spent millions on their infrastructure and I suspect if you arent sure where to start, you should just use a freely available service.